# MPI Persistent Channels -- multiple outstanding requests on a single channel

Tags: mpi

I have a question about persistent p2p channels in MPI.

First, I'll explain my situation using Irecv / Wait and then will ask about persistent channels. I have a situation where I want to issue multiple Irecv commands with the same parameters before issuing the corresponding Wait.

Example:

```
MPI_Request reqs[3];
MPI_Irecv(params..., &req[0]);
MPI_Irecv(params..., &req[1]);
MPI_Irecv(params..., &req[2]);

...

MPI_Wait(req[0]);
MPI_Wait(req[1]);
MPI_Wait(req[2]);
```

where params are all the same.

Could I convert this to using the *same* persistent channel where I'm able to issue the `MPI_Start` three times on the same request that I got from `MPI_Recv_init`, and then call `MPI_Wait` three times on that same request? My guess is no, but it seems a bit odd to have three identical persistent channels.

Is there a recommended way to do this sort of thing?

Note that what I'm describing above doesn't seem to work as I desired as I'm getting this error:

```
MPI_Request req;
MPI_Recv_init(params..., &req);
MPI_Start(&req);
MPI_Start(&req);
```

This produces the error:

```
MPI_Start(108): MPI_Start(request=0x7fc1dede9284) failed
MPI_Start(84).: Persistent request passed to MPI_Start or MPI_Startall is already active.
```

Is there another structure in MPI that would serve this need, or should I just stick with an array of `MPI_Reqeust`s?

Comment: can you please upload a [MCVE] of the code that is **not** working ?

Comment: at first glance, you can only `MPI_Start(); MPI_Wait();` three times in a row.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet yes that seems to be the case -- I've added an example above that produces the said error message. It seems that I must have an individual request for each outstanding `MPI_Start`